# SQL Query - Using value on above lines and replicating down

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to write a query which starts with a value at the start of the year, and adds a line value to that and continues throughout the period.

For example -

I start with 100 employees in week 1 - My table now looks like this

```
Week 1 | Site Name | 100 | 0 Arrivals | 0 Leavers
```

In week 2, I have 10 arrivals so it should now look like

```
Week 2 | Site Name | 110 | 10 Arrivals | 0 Leavers
```

My issue then is I want to predict what I will have in Weeks 3 - 52. I know my Arrival and I know my Leaver numbers, but how do I bring 110 down, add it to Week 3 values, and then move that on again to Week 4 etc?

The problem I keep having is that I am constantly only trying to add to my current headcount, and not being able to roll the total forward.

In the example image below, on line 3 I need the cross to be 152 as previous week I had 150, 3 arrivals - 1 leaver = 152. instead I have the 134 I started with + the 2 which is incorrect.

The 4th line would still be 152, and the same on the 5th + 6th. The 7th line should however then be 153.

I am sorry if this isn't the most clear example.

Our DB engine is Windows SQL Server 2016 Standard.

[image: Example]

Comment: (1) Show your desired results as a text table *in the query*.  (2) What database are you using?

Comment: If you have a database what supports window functions/analytic queries, take a look at LAG, LEAD, and SUM/COUNT OVER ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING. Always mention what db engine you use when posting on SO